# Redirecting command line output

Tags: powershell

I am calling external application **NetworkAPITest.exe** using PowerShell function like this:

```
Function Exec-NetworkAPITest {
    [CmdletBinding()]  
    param
    (
       [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       [String]$Option,
       [String]$Server,
       [String]$Value      
    )

    $Command = ".\NetworkApiTest.exe"
 
    try {
       write-host '>>> NetworkAPITest.exe' $Option $Server $Value
       write-host ''
       & "$Command" $Option $Server $Value      
    } catch {
       write-host '*** ERROR: executing NetworkAPITest.exe'
       write-host '***' $PSItem.ToString()
    }
    write-host ''
    write-host '*** DONE ***'
}
```

And I redirect the output of my script to a text file like this:

```
PS C:\temp> .\myscript.ps1 *> log.txt
```

But, then I got error:

```
NetworkTest.exe : 
At C:\temp\myscript.ps1:789 char:8
+        & "$Command" $Option $Server $Value
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

How should I write that Exec-NetworkAPITest() function so I can get all my script output redirected to a text file using *> log.txt

Comment: `$Command` is `NetworkApiTest` but the log shows `NetworkTest` so I assume something in your question is wrong. That asside, I'd show what command will get executed by adding a `Write-Output "$command $Option $Server $Value"` right before executing it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. But, I found an answer to my question which I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by using Invoke-Expression and redirect the output to a text file. Then display the content of that text file.

```
Function Exec-NetworkAPITest_2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]  
    param
    (
       [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       [String]$Option,
       [String]$Server,
       [String]$Value      
    )
 
    try {
       write-host '>>> NetworkAPITest.exe' $Option $Server $Value
       write-host ''
       $c = "& .\NetworkApiTest.exe "+$Option+' '+$Server+' '+$Value 
       Invoke-Expression $c 2>&1 > psscript.tmp
       Get-Content psscript.tmp
    } catch {
       write-host '*** ERROR: executing NetworkAPITest.exe'
       write-host '***' $PSItem.ToString()
    }
    write-host ''
    write-host '*** DONE ***'
}
```

Comment: You don't need `Invoke-Expression`. You can use the [call](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) operator on its own. You use it in the string you build anyway. It would be like: `& '.\NetworkApiTest.exe'  $arrayOfArgs`